# Surface integral (algebraic solution)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the part of the cone $$z^2=x^2+y^2$$ that lies inside the cylinder $$x^2+y^2=2ay$$

I would like an algebraic solution.

This is how I set it up:

$$\int\int_Sds = \sqrt{2}\int\int_Drdrd\theta$$
where the region is $$D: x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$$

$$\sqrt{2}\int_0^b\int_0^ardrd\theta$$

where $$b=2\pi$$

when I solve this I get $$\sqrt{2} \pi a^2$$ the correct answer is $$2 \sqrt{2}\pi a^2$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the cone has 2 parts, in both $+z$ and $-z$ region

Comment: How would I show that in the integral? Shouldn't they cancel out if it is both positive and in the negative region?

Comment: you are talking about "area" of the cone, there shouldn't be cancellation

Comment: Isn't it "negative" area in the z-direction? For example we have negative area in one-dimension integration so I am wondering why it isn't the case here

Comment: For "surface area", it should never be negative and it is different from "area under the curve"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the insight from fellow user mastrok:

[image: conescyl]